# Positioning Flutter widgets off screen

Tags: flutter

As the title mentioned, I'm trying to position my widget off screen. Currently I have managed to offset the a widget image off screen however it is not the outcome I had expect. The image that is off screen is still visible on the status bar.

This is how it looked like

[image: wrong results image]

This is how i expect it should look like (designed in adobe XD)

[image: expected outcome]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.primaryBackground,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/Splash.png',
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          alignment: new Alignment(1.4, -1.2),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I have tried using a `Positioned` widget within a `Stack`, however it caused more issue of overflow when i try adding new widgets to the `Stack`'s children.

I'm sure there is a proper method of placing a widget in an absolute position. Anyone able to help me with that?

Comment: Post an image which shows your expectation.

Comment: @ArnoldParge Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I've added the sizedBox with a height of 200 to push the text lower to the middle of the screen to continue the children for the Column if not all the column would start at the top.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Palette.primaryBackground,
        child: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.clip,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: -60,
              right: -80,
              child: Image.asset('assets/Splash.png'),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                  ),
                  Text('hello'),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using [transform: Matrix4.translationValues()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math/Matrix4/Matrix4.translationValues.html) and use MediaQueries to position.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.primaryBackground,
        body: Container(
          child: Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
//             alignment: new Alignment(1.4, -1.2),
          ),
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8, -50.0, 0.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it returns the same results, the image still overflows above the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stack with overflow visible:

```
 Stack(
  overflow: Overflow.visible,
  children: <Widget>[
    //using Positioned to control position
  ],
)
```

Comment: Changing the overflow value to `Overflow.clip` works however, if i add another widget in my column (same level as Stack), it gives me an error of `A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.` . Any ideas why?