# How to make text look like its going out of screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am making my app in which I want the font to look like its going out of the screen or has been cut off. I am unable to find anything in flutter related to it. If anyone knows about it please check the picture and let me know if its possible then how can I make it.

[image: Picture of text]

Comment: I think this one can help you. Try to use Positioned within Stack
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61936772/11317365

Comment: Positioned with stack giving render widget error

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-text-wrapping-ellipsis-4fa70b19d316

Comment: Nope. I want the first and last letter to be partially visible like their body will be half outside the app and half inside the app

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Transform.scale(
        scaleX: 1.3,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
           transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                7.0, 50.0, 0.0),
          child: Text('Groupp', 
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This solution is good for one side only like for left but at the same time it ruins right side. Both G and R (the starting and ending letter) should be cut in half out of screen that's what the aim is

Comment: I edited my answer @AliAkbar. Change the values according to your requirement.